# Is it my code or is Sidekiq slow because it's not supposed to access Rails models?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I used to wrap a lot of my code inside of `Thread.new {}` and then started stumbling across Sidekiq to make background tasks a little bit more easier. After a few weeks now, it's been disappointing, and I can't figure out if it's the way I'm putting code into my sidekiq workers or what the deal is.

For example,

```
[1] pry(#<DomainWorker>)> domain = Domain.find_by(unique_id: @unique_id)
[2] pry(#<DomainWorker>)> urls
=> [{:url=>"http://admin.example.com/"}, {:url=>"http://example.com/"}, {:url=>"http://www.example.com/"}, {:url=>"https://admin.example.com/"}, {:url=>"https://example.com/"}, {:url=>"https://www.example.com/"}]
[3] pry(#<DomainWorker>)> domain.domain_urls.build(urls)
=> [#<DomainUrl:0x0000557c97f2a3c8 id: nil, domain_id: 32, url: "http://admin.example.com/", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 #<DomainUrl:0x0000557c97cc6e38 id: nil, domain_id: 32, url: "http://example.com/", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 #<DomainUrl:0x0000557c97cadd70 id: nil, domain_id: 32, url: "http://www.example.com/", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 #<DomainUrl:0x0000557c97c9c8e0 id: nil, domain_id: 32, url: "https://admin.example.com/", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 #<DomainUrl:0x0000557c97c7ed18 id: nil, domain_id: 32, url: "https://example.com/", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>,
 #<DomainUrl:0x0000557c97c43df8 id: nil, domain_id: 32, url: "https://www.example.com/", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
```

Just to simply run the `domain.domain_urls.build(urls)` command took about 15 seconds to execute. If I open up `rails c`, this command runs instantaneously.

Is this against best practices to manipulate models from a sidekiq worker or something? Not sure why this would take 15-20 seconds sometimes, 5 seconds the next time, etc. It's very inconsistent. I even have a MailWorker that sometimes either takes 2 seconds to send an email, or 2 minutes. Not sure what the deal is.

Here's my `config/sidekiq.yml` configuration file:

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 50
production:  
  :concurrency: 50
:queues:
  - default
```

Is it my code or is Sidekiq just not good at doing these tasks? What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Simply disabling `eager_load` in my development environment seems to make *some* progress.

In `config/environments/development.rb`:

changed

`config.eager_load = false`

to

`config.eager_load = true`

It works for awhile, but then it starts hanging again after a bunch of tasks are queued up and completed. Now it's stuck again.

If I run `show processlist` in MySQL, I see the following:

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+----+------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| Id | User       | Host      | db                | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| 31 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   | 1017 |          | NULL                  |
| 50 | root       | localhost | NULL              | Query   |    0 | starting | show full processlist |
| 55 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   | 1059 |          | NULL                  |
| 57 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   | 1028 |          | NULL                  |
| 58 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   |  420 |          | NULL                  |
| 61 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   | 1078 |          | NULL                  |
| 62 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   |  425 |          | NULL                  |
| 63 | app_dev | localhost | app_portal_dev | Sleep   |  191 |          | NULL                  |
+----+------------+-----------+-------------------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Furthermore, if I send the kill TTIN signal to the Sidekiq worker, this is the output:

```
2018-11-03T03:20:29.415Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: Thread TID-gsr4jqd7l processor
2018-11-03T03:20:29.415Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `select'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:363:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `block in read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:251:in `io'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `block in call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:232:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:370:in `ensure_connected'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:307:in `logging'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:281:in `with_socket_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:209:in `call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1172:in `block in _bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1169:in `_bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1214:in `brpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:89:in `get_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:99:in `fetch'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2018-11-03T03:20:29.416Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: Thread TID-gsr4jqddx processor
2018-11-03T03:20:29.416Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `select'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:363:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `block in read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:251:in `io'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `block in call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:232:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:370:in `ensure_connected'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:307:in `logging'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:281:in `with_socket_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:209:in `call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1172:in `block in _bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1169:in `_bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1214:in `brpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:89:in `get_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:99:in `fetch'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2018-11-03T03:20:29.416Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: Thread TID-gsr4jqdh1 processor
2018-11-03T03:20:29.416Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `select'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:363:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `block in read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:251:in `io'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `block in call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:232:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:370:in `ensure_connected'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:307:in `logging'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:281:in `with_socket_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:209:in `call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1172:in `block in _bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1169:in `_bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1214:in `brpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:89:in `get_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:99:in `fetch'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2018-11-03T03:20:29.417Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: Thread TID-gsr4jqcuh processor
2018-11-03T03:20:29.417Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `select'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:363:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `block in read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:251:in `io'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `block in call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:232:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:370:in `ensure_connected'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:307:in `logging'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:281:in `with_socket_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:209:in `call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1172:in `block in _bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1169:in `_bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1214:in `brpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:89:in `get_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:99:in `fetch'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2018-11-03T03:20:29.417Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: Thread TID-gsr4jqd4p processor
2018-11-03T03:20:29.417Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `select'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:363:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `block in read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:251:in `io'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `block in call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:232:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:370:in `ensure_connected'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:307:in `logging'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:281:in `with_socket_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:209:in `call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1172:in `block in _bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1169:in `_bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1214:in `brpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:89:in `get_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:99:in `fetch'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
2018-11-03T03:20:29.418Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: Thread TID-gsr4jqcn5 processor
2018-11-03T03:20:29.418Z 65977 TID-gsr3safel WARN: /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `select'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:68:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:64:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:56:in `gets'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:363:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:263:in `block in read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:251:in `io'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `read'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `block in call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:232:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:370:in `ensure_connected'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:222:in `block in process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:307:in `logging'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `process'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:210:in `block in call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:281:in `with_socket_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:209:in `call_with_timeout'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1172:in `block in _bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1169:in `_bpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis.rb:1214:in `brpop'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `block in retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:95:in `block in redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:64:in `block in with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `handle_interrupt'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/connection_pool-2.2.2/lib/connection_pool.rb:61:in `with'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq.rb:92:in `redis'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/fetch.rb:36:in `retrieve_work'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:89:in `get_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:99:in `fetch'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sidekiq-5.2.2/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Comment: Are there any validations configured in your `DomainUrl`? How many `DomainUrl` are there? Do you have appropriate indexes on your `domain_urls` table? What database pool size do you have configured in your `database.yml`?

Comment: can you put additional logs in your code and see where it get late. job start or execution?

Comment: where is your redis? local or remote. whats the timeout setting?

Answer (score 1):

Rails development mode autoloading is single-threaded.  You can set Sidekiq to whatever concurrency you want but you will still have a gigantic mutex to single-thread your jobs so they can autoload safely.  Turning on eager_load or switching to production mode disables autoloading.

concurrency: 50 is way too high.  Don't set it higher than 25.

It's also possible you have a huge number of threads but not the same amount of database connections, set `pool: 25` in `config/database.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong with the TTIN output or with the database. Sidekiq perfectly fits working with Rails and ActiveRecord. We run a high-load production environment with around 30k concurrent threads (spreaded across a few dozens worker servers) and Sidekiq performs exceptionally. Don't set unnecessary high concurrency in development mode, although if you're playing with a single task that doesn't really matter.

Try debugging Sidekiq worker locally - set breakpoint at the beginning of your method and find where it gets slow. It's unlikely that Sidekiq itself is up to that